# South appears to be loading initial_data.json twice

Tags: python, django, django-south

I've been working with South on a new Django project.

I've just added a new model `Client`, and I'd like to make ensure that any of the tests that get run, or any new database setups, always get populated with an instance of `Client`, so I've added a new instance into the project's `initial_data.json`.

Now whenever I run the tests, or populate a new database, **it looks like `initial_data.json` is being loaded twice** - once after the tables are first created. (which fails with a traceback). and a second time, after the migrations have been applied. (which succeeds just fine)

For instance, running `manage.py syncdb --migrate --noinput` gives me the following output:

```
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
<snip>
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Problem installing fixture 'initial_data.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 174, in handle
    obj.save(using=using)
  File ".../django/core/serializers/base.py", line 165, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File ".../django/db/models/base.py", line 522, in save_base
    manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val).exists())):
  File ".../django/db/models/query.py", line 496, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File ".../django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 424, in has_results
    return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File ".../django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 735, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".../django/db/backends/util.py", line 34, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".../django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 234, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
DatabaseError: no such table: core_client 
Migrating...
Running migrations for core:
<snip>
 - Loading initial data for assetcloud.
Installed 5 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

Or, if I run `manage.py test SouthProblems` on the following test:

```
class SouthProblems(TestCase):
    def test_south_problems(self):
        print Client.objects.all()
```

I'll get this output:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Problem installing fixture 'initial_data.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
<snip, as before>
DatabaseError: no such table: core_client

[<Client: example>]
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.013s

OK
```

In both cases the initial data does appear to have been successfully created, but I'm getting unnecessary tracebacks.

I'm wondering if I'm not quite using South correctly wrt. initial data fixtures?

I also tracked this ticket down: http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/372 which sounds like what I'm seeing, but that was 18 months ago, and the ticket is marked as fixed.

I'm running Django 1.3, and South 0.7.3

**EDIT:**

I've also seen this: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html#initial-data-and-post-syncdb although I'm not totally sure from the documentation notes if I should expect to see South attempting to load the fixtures before any migrations have been applied.

There's this https://groups.google.com/d/topic/south-users/PWpQn61UDmI/discussion, which suggests that using initial_data might not be a sensible thing to do with South, but I'm somewhat surprised I've not seen the same thing mentioned elsewhere?...  (I've posted a question to the list there, too, but it's awaiting moderation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended solution is not to use initial data fixtures with South at all, but to call loaddata from inside a migration instead:

See this discussion on Google Groups - 
[link](http://groups.google.com/group/south-users/browse_thread/thread/3d6a509fad540e62?pli=1)

Comment: Yup just ran across the same thread.  Assuming this is what other folks are currently doing ATM?  I'll mark this as accepted if no-one else comes up with anything more in-depth.  Still slightly surprised not to have seen this mentioned anywhere except that one thread - surely it's something people would be running into quite a lot?

Comment: I can't actually remember what I did when it happened to me! I guess I must have used a data migration in some way or other.

Comment: Yup loading the fixture explicitly inside a data migration seems like the right thing to do.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately does not work anymore since django 1.6.

http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1328